# DynamicInvoke Number of parameter does not match expected count

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to wrap a lambda inside of `Func<..>` assigned to dynamic and call it dynamically but it throws an exception about parameter count.

MCVE

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // your code goes here
        try {
            dynamic plus = new Func<long, long, long>((a, b) => a + b);
            Type functionType = plus.GetType();
            int arity = functionType.GetGenericArguments().Length - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Arity {0}", arity);
            long[] parameters = new long[arity];

            long result = plus.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Exception: `Number of parameter does not match expected count.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DynamicInvoke` takes an `object` array as a parameter, not a `long` array.

This should work:

```
var result = plus.DynamicInvoke(parameters.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: Rather than casting and allocating a brand new array, it's probably better to declare `parameters` as object[] to begin with

Comment: @KevinGosse, I agree. Although  in this particular case the cost of dynamically invoking the delegate is much higher that the allocation of the array. The main point is that the input needs to be a `object[]`.